# Understanding use of where in subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

List the name and continent of countries in the continents containing either Argentina or Australia. Order by name of the country.

[image]

> From https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial, question 3

This is what I tried

```
select name, continent
from world
where continent = (select continent 
   from world where name in ('Argentina',' Australia'))
order by name
```

Thought it was about equivalence, so tried this

```
select name, continent
from world
where continent in (select continent 
   from world where name in ('Argentina',' Australia'))
order by name
```

and this seems to be the solution

```
select name, continent
from world
where continent = (select continent 
   from world where name ='Argentina')
or continent = (select continent 
   from world where name ='Australia')
order by name
```

I'm trying to understand the logical flaw in my solution.

Comment: The last two queries are equivalent.

Comment: @AdR, here you are trying to find, why does your answer not in the given answer, and your 2nd answer is better than the given solution (if you remove the space in front of Australia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue subquery in your first result will return multiple rows, and you can't use equal sign there so you have to check 'in' clause.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
select name,continent from world
     where continent IN ( select continent
     from world where name IN ('Argentina','Australia')) 
     ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution is correct, but because of the single space before ' **A**ustralia' in query `(select continent from world where name IN ('Argentina',**' Australia'**) )` is giving you wrong output. You are not getting Continent name Oceania.

I hope this has given you clarity on the query.

```
select name,continent from world 
where continent IN 
(select continent from world where name IN ('Argentina','Australia')) 
order by name
```